# data.frame slicing

Tags: string, r, dataframe, slice

I hope this question is not too simple for this board.

I have created a data.frame df:

```
       CAS        Name        CID
89  13010-47-4   Lomustine         3950
90 130209-82-4   Latanoprost       5311221,5282380,46705340,3890
91 130636-43-0   Nifekalant        268083
92 130929-57-6   Entacapone        5281081
```

and a vector vec

```
[1] 5282380 18471829 45923789 44308022 44266812 24883465 24867475 24867460
```

I would like to extract the rows of df which contains any number of vec. I tried to solve this problem by this code:

```
 df$GC[(df$CID %in% vec)] = 1

 df[df$GC==1,]
```

But the problem with this solution is, that I only get the rows, which contain only one number in the CID column. Rows which contain several values in CID like line 90 do not appear.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your comment on EDi's answer (which I like) I thought I'd make a suggestion.

Squeezing comma separated values into a single column of a data frame is awkward and (in my experience) just leads to frustration. I often find it simpler to keep it in a separate data structure, a list:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "       CAS        Name        CID
   13010-47-4   Lomustine         3950
  130209-82-4   Latanoprost       5311221,5282380,46705340,3890
  130636-43-0   Nifekalant        268083
  130929-57-6   Entacapone        5281081",sep = "",header = TRUE)

cid <- sapply(dat$CID,strsplit,",",USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

In this form, things are often easier to work with:

```
ID <- c(5282380, 18471829, 45923789, 44308022, 44266812, 24883465, 24867475, 24867460, 3950)
dat[sapply(cid,function(x) {any(x %in% as.character(ID))}),]
          CAS        Name                           CID
1  13010-47-4   Lomustine                          3950
2 130209-82-4 Latanoprost 5311221,5282380,46705340,3890
```

You can always use rownames in `dat` and the names of the list to keep each item straight, if you're worried about orderings changing.

(Also note that my anonymous function is assuming that `ID` will be found eventually by R's scoping rules; you can alter the function to pass in `ID` explicitly if you like.)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Working with sqeezing comma separated values is really frustrating :)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use grep():

```
> txt <- "       CAS        Name        CID
+   13010-47-4   Lomustine         3950
+  130209-82-4   Latanoprost       5311221,5282380,46705340,3890
+  130636-43-0   Nifekalant        268083
+  130929-57-6   Entacapone        5281081
+ "
> con <- textConnection(txt)
> df <- read.table(con, header = TRUE)
> close(con)
> ID <- c(5282380, 18471829, 45923789, 44308022, 44266812, 24883465, 24867475, 24867460, 3950)
> grep(paste("\\b", ID, "\\b", sep="", collapse = "|"), dat$CID)
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: Nice. FYI, as of R-2.14, and thanks to R-core, you can read the text data in in a single command, `txt <- read.table(text="Body of table")`, avoiding the explicit opening and closing of connections.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The Problem with this solution is, that e.g. an ID "08" would find several rows, although these rows only contain the digits. Is it possible to select only rows which contain the complete number in between the commas e.g. "5282380" and not only "52823" or "2380"?

Comment: In addition to Joran's fine approach above, you could fix EDi's regular expression so that it only matches the exact strings in ID.  Here's how:  `grep(paste("\\b", ID, "\\b", sep="", collapse = "|"), dat$CID)`. (For more info, see `?regexp`, which explains that "The symbol ‘\b’ matches the empty string at either edge of a word".)

Comment: @Josh+ EDi thanks for this useful informations. It works perfect.